# Plotting error bars for factorplot in Seaborn without bootstrapping

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

When using `factorplot` in Seaborn, confidence intervals are calculated for the estimator using bootstrapping. Is there any way of specifying alternate ways of extracting an interval? For example, if my data are MCMC simulation outputs or themselves bootstrap samples, it does not make sense to bootstrap -- I just want to use the appropriate quantiles for the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Here's my short-term solution in the case of `seaborn.pointplot`:

If the relevant seaborn code is:

```py
seaborn.pointplot(x="value", y="parameters", data=dfm, ci=50, join=False)
```

where we want 50 to be the interval without bootstrapping, then this bit of plotnine code does virtually the same thing:

```
g = plotnine.ggplot(data=dfm) + plotnine.geom_pointrange(
            mapping=plotnine.aes(x="parameters",y="value"),
            stat = "summary",
            fun_ymin=lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25),
            fun_ymax=lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75),
            fun_y=np.mean,
        ) + plotnine.coord_flip()
```

No manipulation of the dataframe needed.